# Пагинация не работает

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination

Ребят, помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться с плагином Pagination.js или может есть какой-нибудь другой хороший? Есть список товаров в магазине, нужно разбить его на части. Убил уже много времени, не получается реализовать.

```js
$("#pagination-container").pagination({
  dataSource: [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,
  ],
  pageSize: 12,
  autoHidePrevious: true,
  autoHideNext: true,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    // template method of yourself

    var html = template(dataSource);
    $("#data-container").html(html);
  },
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.5.0/pagination.min.js"></script>
<div id="data-container"></div>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>
```

Но при генерации страницы вылетает ошибка "template is not defined". Буду очень признателен за помощь.

Comment: js код не добавили

Comment: Блин, не получается вставить нормально код

Comment: у редактора есть кнопки специальные...а в целом это markdown (если это о чём-то говорит)

Comment: *template is not defined* --- так а где вы определили необходимую функцию, чтобы к ней обращаться?

Comment: Пагинация работает, вы просто не объявили функцию `template`.

Comment: В документации на github есть пример [функции-шаблонизатора](https://github.com/superRaytin/paginationjs#rendering-data). Обратите внимание, что эта функция принимает аргумент `data`, переданный в callback-функцию, а не `dataSource`

Comment: Спасибо за ответы) все равно что-то не догоняю, на сайте https://pagination.js.org/ в документации все работает, без обьявления функции. Не могли бы вы подсказать что надо сделать?). И на странице у меня есть 100 товаров. let items = document.querySelectorAll(".articles__item"); Мне нужно положить их в dataSource: вместо цифр 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 вот так вот dataSource(Array.from(items .length))?

Comment: да и так и так не работает, я туда и data кладу)

Comment: Ну а почему я сделал по документации с github и у меня работает? https://codepen.io/gene_erbin/pen/dyjGKPY

Comment: Видимо я глупый) спасибо большое за помощь, если я правильно понял, то мы вставляем товары в html через js? а я думал можно это сделать оставив 100 карточек в html

Comment: Добра всем кто ответил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В документации плагина **Pagination.js** на [GitHub](https://github.com/superRaytin/paginationjs#quick-start) указан пример функции, которая определяет структуру вывода данных, подлежащих пагинации. В представленном примере данные будут выводиться неупорядоченным списком, в котором каждый элемент данных обёрнут в тег `<li>`:

```
function simpleTemplating(data) {
    var html = "<ul>";
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        html += '<li>'+ item +'</li>';
    });
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}
```

Эта функция вызывается при инициализации пагинации внутри функции-callback'а, формируя вывод первой "порции" данных (количество элементов данных из `dataSource`, обрабатываемых функцией за раз и выводимых на одной странице пагинации, зависит от параметра `pageSize`).

```
$('#pagination-container').pagination({
    dataSource: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... , 195],
    pageSize: 3,
    callback: function(data, pagination) {
        var html = simpleTemplating(data);
        $('#data-container').html(html);
    }
})
```

Затем эта функция вызывается каждый раз при клике на элементы навигации (номера страниц и стрелочки), обращаясь к `dataSource`, получая нужное количество элементов данных со сдвигом, зависящим от номера активной страницы пагинации.

Плагин **Pagination.js** предполагает, что исходные данные для пагинации хранятся внутри js-кода, меняя структуру DOM только вставляя нужное количество элементов данных в контейнер с данными пагинации `<div id="data-container"></div>`, удаляя их и вставляя новые при каждом клике на элементы навигации.

Если данные для пагинации изначально представлены элементами `html`, а функция, определяющая структуру вывода, будет переносить элементы из их изначального положения в структуре страницы в контейнер с данными пагинации:

```
<div class="item">item1</div>
<div class="item">item2</div>
<div class="item">item3</div>

const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

$("#pagination-container").pagination({
  dataSource: [...items],
  pageSize: 3,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    var html = simpleTemplating(data);
    $("#data-container").html(html);
  },
});

function simpleTemplating(data) {
    const html = new DocumentFragment();
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        html.append(item);
    });
    return html;
}
```

то при инициализации пагинации только первые `n` элементов (`n` указано в параметре `pageSize`), будут перемещены со своей позиции в контейнер данных для пагинации:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При перемещении между страницами элементы данных будут перемещаться из изначальной позиции в контейнер с данными пагинации в соответствии с выбранной страницей пагинации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чтобы избежать отображения элементов данных в структуре страницы до того, как они переместятся в контейнер с данными пагинации, предлагаю при выводе этих элементов добавить им атрибут `hidden`, а в функции `simpleTemplating` удалять этот атрибут.

Итоговый код представлен ниже. [CSS](https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.5.0/pagination.css) для элементов пагинации был взят с сайта плагина **Pagination.js**

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

$("#pagination-container").pagination({
  dataSource: [...items],
  autoHidePrevious: true,
  autoHideNext: true,
  pageSize: 3,
  callback: function(data, pagination) {
    var html = simpleTemplating(data);
    $("#data-container").html(html);
  },
});

function simpleTemplating(data) {
    const html = new DocumentFragment();
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        item.removeAttribute('hidden');
        html.append(item);
    });
    return html;
}
```

```css
.paginationjs {
 display:flex;
 line-height:1.6;
 font-family:Marmelad,"Lucida Grande",Arial,"Hiragino Sans GB",Georgia,sans-serif;
 font-size:14px;
 box-sizing:initial
}
.paginationjs:after {
 display:table;
 content:" ";
 clear:both
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages {
 float:left;
 margin-left:10px
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages ul {
 float:left;
 margin:0;
 padding:0
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li {
 float:left;
 border:1px solid #aaa;
 border-right:none;
 list-style:none
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li>a {
 min-width:30px;
 height:28px;
 line-height:28px;
 display:block;
 background:#fff;
 font-size:14px;
 color:#333;
 text-decoration:none;
 text-align:center;
 cursor:pointer
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li>a:hover {
 background:#eee
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li.active {
 border:none
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li.active>a {
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 background:#aaa;
 color:#fff;
 cursor:default
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li.disabled>a {
 opacity:.3;
 cursor:default
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li.disabled>a:hover {
 background:0 0
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li:first-child,
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li:first-child>a {
 border-radius:3px 0 0 3px
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li:last-child {
 border-right:1px solid #aaa;
 border-radius:0 3px 3px 0
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li:last-child>a {
 border-radius:0 3px 3px 0
}
.paginationjs .paginationjs-nav {
 float:left;
 height:30px;
 line-height:30px;
 font-size:14px
}
.paginationjs>:first-child {
 margin-left:0
}

.paginationjs .paginationjs-pages li.paginationjs-next {
 border-right:1px solid #aaa\9
}
#data-container {
  overflow: auto;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
#data-container div {
  background: #EEE;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  padding: 8px;
  line-height: 1em;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pagination.js.org/dist/2.5.0/pagination.min.js"></script>

<div id="data-container"></div>
<div id="pagination-container"></div>

<div class="item" hidden>item1</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item2</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item3</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item4</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item5</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item6</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item7</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item8</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item9</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item10</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item11</div>
<div class="item" hidden>item12</div>
```

Comment: Лучи добра тебе дружище, лайки пока ставить не могу

Comment: @Роман Спасибо за лучи) Если ответ помог, можешь нажать на серую галку рядом с ответом.